# how to get the file name from directory in python

Tags: python

I want to get the file name in my directory to use it as dynamically in ml model.

```
import os

i = os.listdir('./upload')[0]
print(i)

# ...read data from file `i`...
```

Comment: Take a look at `os.path.basename`.

Comment: or look at `pathlib`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that `os.listdir` returns file names not file paths. So you need to add the directory name to your filepath:

`cv2.imread(os.path.join('upload', i))`

Or you can use `glob` which returns paths:

```
import glob
import cv2

for image_path in glob.glob('./upload/*.jpg'):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
```